# Getting Squarespace to add Access-control-allow-origin header

Tags: cors, web-audio-api, squarespace

I'm trying to load some audio files into a squarespace page that will be run through Web Audio API and I get the following error:
"MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for..." 
I inspected the response header from the Squarespace site it does not have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  From what I understand, Web Audio API requires the header or else it outputs zeros.  Is there a way to get Squarespace to add the header in the response or am going to be forced to find a different solution?  I need to process the audio with the API so I can't use HTML's `<audio>` elements which would work.

Comment: One possible alternative to consider is what’s described in the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/441757

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm going to try it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to allow cross-origin requests to assets stored on a Squarespace site. The assets are served from Squarespace's global CDN (unspecific to your website) and, correspondingly, they don't provide access to change such restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So I guess I will try to use an external CORS proxy to add the header to the requests.